# Html.ActionLink, Url.ActionLink and Html.RouteLink return empty urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, actionlink, routelink

Html.ActionLink, Url.ActionLink and Html.RouteLink return empty urls, even though the target url is valid and displayed properly from url?

I played around with the route but, it keeps return empty url without any exception.

Comment: I'm having this same issue whilst upgrading to MVC 3 RC2.

Comment: You need to give us more information if we're going to help you. Your Routes, the link you're making with `RouteLink`, and your controller/actions you're trying to call with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when upgrading my project from mvc2 to mvc3.
The problem was in old **global.asax** file, that I put into new project.

So when I replaced old .asax onto new, actionLinks start to work properly.

**Global.asax** for mvc3

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace RealtyMVC
{
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    //!!!add this method
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //!!!and add this call
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
}
```